# Performance of SqlParameter object in C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am working with a large accounting software in C# which uses stored procedure parameter being added using `SqlParameter` objects:

```
SqlCommand sccmd = new SqlCommand("AccountGroupAdd", sqlcon);
sccmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter sprmparam = new SqlParameter();

sprmparam = sccmd.Parameters.Add("@accountGroupName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sprmparam.Value = accountgroupinfo.AccountGroupName;
```

Now I want to know if replace this by removing `SqlParameter` object as

```
SqlCommand sccmd = new SqlCommand("AccountGroupAdd", sqlcon);
            sccmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sccmd.Parameters.Add("@accountGroupName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = accountgroupinfo.AccountGroupName;
```

Increase the performance of the application?

Comment: Why do you need to ask us when you can test it for yourself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question can be answered simply by testing the code.

Comment: No, this won't increase your application performance. ...

Answer (score 0):

Create object spends time, so below code must need time to create.

```
SqlParameter sprmparam = new SqlParameter();
```

Massive of above will spend significant time.

Comment: creation done only once in each class. but assigning to this object done several times.